# web report with stylessheets

Tags: templates, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need to create some database-driven reports and instead of recreating the wheel yet again, I was curious if there were any sites that listed reporting type templates.  I know there are tons of free templates to download for the front-end/GUI but there are too many to look at for something that might work for the back-end.  So, I was hoping someone here might have some recommendations.  I'm using Cooldfusion but for layout work, but it doesn't really mater what language (asp, php) as I can adapt it to work for CF.

Answer (score 1):

Coldfusion 9 has [CFgrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7baf.html) which will aid in both the back end and front end side of reporting but isn't the prettiest thing in the world. Also [cfchart](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7930.html) which will give chart based reporting. They both have a large amount of customisability and are already built in to CF.

Finally theres [cfreport](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c1d.html) which does what it says on the tin. Its a much simpler tag to use and has less visual impact but allows you to attach a stylesheet to override its styles and will output in a good selection of document types.

I'd encourage you to look at these tools inside CF before looking at 3rd party reporting solutions.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: I'm aware of these tools but I was looking more for an admin type of template.  Most of the reports will be excel-type looking grids with tables.  The column headings may be sortable at some time in the future.  I found a few on ThemeForest after posting this so I may find something there.  +1 for the items you mentioned though but just not what I was looking for in the sense of templates.

Comment: After some more googling, looks like what I'm looking for is an admin skin.

Answer (score 0):

[ThemeForest](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates&ei=npwFUJb3KqPu2gWrgKWWBQ&usg=AFQjCNHsq45JOIv0zHy0ZLI08uaGNIXhMg&sig2=cPs_Tpk-wsPit_gMBV_c4w) has a lot of choices for an admin skin.  The link will take you directly to the admin template area.